# swapping nodes for a bubble sort doubly linked list C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

Welp I'm back.  I am now trying to do a bubble sort with a node swap.  There is a problem in my algorithm that i cannot determine.  When I remove the bool condition to determine if the list is sorted, the program produces some output, indicating the loop condition is failing to a problem in the algorithm.  i have diagrammed out what happens on paper, with each pointer as it is reassigned.  I envisioned nodes a b c d, where b and c are swapped.  the sort function is below.  i have made notes for every action in an attempt to figure what i am doing wrong.  no dice, any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```c
void sortList(void)
{
    struct Node *before, *after;
    struct Node * temp;

    bool sorted = false;

    while (sorted == false)
    {
        //test completion
        sorted = true;  //if this isn't changed by the below statement the list is sorted
        temp = head;    //reinitializes where there list sorts from
        while (temp->next != NULL)  //stops at the end of the list
        {
            if (temp->data > temp->next->data)
            {
                //test the value of the nodes to see if they need a sort

                before = temp->prev;    //"back" pointer for subject (b)
                after = temp->next; //"forward" pointer for subject
                if (before != NULL)
                {
                    before->next = after;   //covers swap being made at beginning
                }
                temp->next = after->next;   //points to after next
                after->next->prev = temp;   //sets prev pointer for "d"
                temp->prev = after; //points to what after pointed
                after->next = temp; //places node after next one
                after->prev = before;   //ditto

                sorted = false; //flagged, the list is not sorted
            }
            temp = temp->next;  //moves through the list

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if(before != NULL)` needs an `else` part: `else{` `head = after;` `}`. Also, `after->next->prev = temp;` should only be done if `after->next` is not `NULL`.

Comment: good points, though something is still breaking the list

Comment: yea I can get it through 1 iteration, but any attempt to run it again fails.  A single iteration gives a correct first step bubble sort

Comment: An additional change required is that the `if (temp->data > temp->next->data)` needs an `else` part, and the `temp = temp->next;` line at the end of the inner loop needs to be moved into the `else` part. This is because the `if` part already advances `temp` one position along the list by swapping link pointers around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main problems in the original `sortList` function:

1. It doesn't update `head` when moving the first node in the list. (Fix: add an `else` part to update `head`.)
2. `after->next->prev` dereferences a null pointer at the end of the list. (Fix: check `after->next != NULL` first.)
3. `temp = temp->next` dereferences a null pointer at the end of the list and skips a position when not at the end of the list. The code that swaps the `temp` node with the following node already advances `temp` one position through the list, so it should not be done again. (Fix: move `temp = temp->next;` into an `else` part executed only when the `temp` node does not need to be swapped.)

Here is an updated version of `sortList()` with the changes marked:

```
void sortList(void)
{
    struct Node *before, *after;
    struct Node * temp;

    bool sorted = false;

    while (sorted == false)
    {
        //test completion
        sorted = true;  //if this isn't changed by the below statement the list is sorted
        temp = head;    //reinitializes where there list sorts from
        while (temp->next != NULL)  //stops at the end of the list
        {
            if (temp->data > temp->next->data)
            {
                //test the value of the nodes to see if they need a sort

                before = temp->prev;    //"back" pointer for subject (b)
                after = temp->next; //"forward" pointer for subject
                if (before != NULL)
                {
                    // temp is not at beginning of list
                    before->next = after;
                }
                else
                {
                    // *** Fix 1 ***
                    // temp is at beginning of list
                    head = after;
                }
                temp->next = after->next;   //points to after next
                if (after->next != NULL) // *** Fix 2 ***
                {
                    after->next->prev = temp;   //sets prev pointer for "d"
                }
                temp->prev = after; //points to what after pointed
                after->next = temp; //places node after next one
                after->prev = before;   //ditto

                sorted = false; //flagged, the list is not sorted
            }
            else // *** Fix 3 ***
            {
                temp = temp->next;  //moves through the list
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The above version of `sortList` fails when `head` is `NULL` (an empty list) due to `temp->next` dereferencing a null pointer. One way to fix it is to mark an empty list as already sorted by changing the initialization of `sorted` as follows:

```
    bool sorted = (head == NULL);
```

The amount of work done by `sortList` can be halved (approximately) by reducing the number of iterations of the inner loop by one after for each iteration of the outer loop. This can be done as follows:

1. Add a new variable `done` to mark the start of the already sorted portion at the end of the list.  Initialize it to `NULL` near the top of the function (before the outer loop):

```
    struct Node *done = NULL;
```

2. Change the condition for the inner loop to terminate at the end of the unsorted portion of the list:

```
    while (sorted == false)
    {
        //test completion
        sorted = true;  //if this isn't changed by the below statement the list is sorted
        temp = head;    //reinitializes where there list sorts from
        while (temp->next != done) // stops at the sorted portion of the list
        {
```

3. When the inner loop has terminated (at the end of the outer loop), the `temp` node and everything beyond it is now sorted, so make `done` point to this node:

```
        }
        done = temp;    // everything from here is already sorted
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized I could have seen it if I had more carefully evaluated the output I was getting.  I had overlooked that it was stepping forward without doing the comparison (among other things).  Anyway thanks much, I am going to tool around a bit with your suggestions below